# Make anchor link download a file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have written below lines of code.

```
for (var counterOfCerticateLoop in certificateDetailsArray) {
    var document_type_id = certificateDetailsArray[counterOfCerticateLoop]['document_type_id'];
    var document_actual_name = certificateDetailsArray[counterOfCerticateLoop]['document_actual_name'];
    var document_unique_name = certificateDetailsArray[counterOfCerticateLoop]['document_unique_name'];
    var document_type = certificateDetailsArray[counterOfCerticateLoop]['document_type'];
    var document_description = certificateDetailsArray[counterOfCerticateLoop]['document_description'];

    var fileURL = '../student/certificates/' + document_unique_name;

    var EditButton = '<button title="Edit" onclick="editContactDetail(\'' + document_type_id + '\')" class="btn btn-primary table_btn btn-outline btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></button>';

    var DeleteButton = '<button title="Delete" onclick="deleteContactDetail(\'' + document_type_id + '\')" class="btn btn-danger  table_btn btn-outline btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></button>';

    var tableRow = '<tr><td>' + document_type + '</td>' +
        '<td><a href=' + fileURL + '>' + document_actual_name + '</a></td>' +
        '<td>' + document_description + '</td>' +
        '<td>' + EditButton + DeleteButton + '</td>';
    $("#certificateTable").append(tableRow);
}
```

The above code creates table perfectly. Now the issue is that we click on file link, it does not get downloaded. I want that it should download the file in fileURL which is rendered in anchor tag's href attribute.

Please help !!!

Comment: `console.log(fileURL)` what you get ?

Comment: What happens when you click on the link?

Comment: it is redirected in another tab of browser where it's content is displayed

Comment: use this @NidaAmin : <a href="file link" download target="_blank">Click here to download</a>

Answer (score 2):

Use HTML5 `download` attribute.

```
<a download href=' + fileURL + '>' + document_actual_name + '</a>
```

*Note: Be aware may be all version of different browser not supported this attribute*

Answer (score 0):

You can put this code in your .htaccess file and try if it works?

```
AddType application/octet-stream .csv
AddType application/octet-stream .xls
AddType application/octet-stream .doc
AddType application/octet-stream .avi
AddType application/octet-stream .mpg
AddType application/octet-stream .mov
AddType application/octet-stream .pdf
```

Comment: Sorry it is not getting downloaded

Comment: What happen when you click on a tag? @NidaAmin

Comment: it is redirected in another tab of browser where it's content is displaye

Comment: `var fileURL = 'www.example.com/student/...` - that is still a relative URL, so unless you had a folder named `www.example.com` in the root of your site, this is of course still nonsense. It would need to be at least `var fileURL = '//www.example.com/student/...`

Comment: I have updated my answer. @CBroe